# Adding a Gradient over a button while hovering it without it affecting the text

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a Gradient over a Button,which has a background image, while hovering it, without the gradient affecting/overlaying the text.

```css
div.test {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f9f9f9, #a2a2a2, #f9f9f9);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -23.5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

div.test:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

div.menuleftbutton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 150px 8% 0px;
  background-color: blue;  /* this would be replaced by an image */
}

div.menuleftbuttontext {
  margin: 23.5px 0px 23.5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuleftbutton">
  <div class="menuleftbuttontext">
  <div class="test">
  </div>
    TEXT GOES HERE              
  </div>
</div>
```

full thingy in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fm6q95wk/1/

The expected Result is that the gradient gets added "under" the text, which this version doesn't.

So far, every version I've tried either lays the gradient over the text or doesn't show the gradient while the mouse is over the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the HTML so you only have one inner and one outer `div`.

I changed the CSS so essentially the inner div is setting the width and height of the outer div. This is because you want the hover effect to cover the whole "button" and I am putting the hover gradient on the inner div, while the outer div gets the background image. Read the comments in the CSS where I explain what each rule is doing.

Notice the use of RGBA on the `linear-gradient`. This is so you can control the opacity of the gradient, I used `0.5` for opacity so it is easier to see the change on hover but you can easily change it back to 0.2 for the exact look are going for. Hex to rgba converter at: http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/ if you need it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menuleftbutton {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200); /* background-image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0; /* just for the demo, change the margin to whatever you need */
  cursor: pointer; /* hover... this makes it feel much more like a button */
}

.menuleftbuttontext {
  width: 260px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 26px; /* decreased the size because it was splitting into 2 lines */
  padding: 0 20px; /* keep text from hitting sides */
  line-height: 80px; /* line-height same as height vertically centers text */
}

.menuleftbutton:hover .menuleftbuttontext { /* style of inner div when outer div is hovered */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.5), rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.5), rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="menuleftbutton">
    <div class="menuleftbuttontext">
      TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  
I just have one small question: I had a similar approach, but every time I moved my cursor over the inner div, the background switched back, because it registered me as hovering the inner, and not hovering the outer div anymore, I think.  
Why isn't this the Case here?

Comment: Look at the last rule in the css. The selector is predicated on hovering over the outer div, which is the only hover rule involved. Treat it like a button, you expect the hover styling when you are over any part of the button, even though in this case the style change is on the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` is probably needed here to separate the text from the button background here. Here is what I have came up with:

html:

```
  <body>
    <div id="menuleft">
      <div id="menuleftsticky">
        <a href="">
          <div class="menuleftbutton">
            <div class="menuleftbuttontext">
              <div class="test">
              </div>
              <div class="buttontext">
                TEST  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
div.buttontext {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 30%;
}
```